Plotting the image of a function of 3 variables in $R^3$
Reading the question  plotting the image of a function under constraints I see that the TransformedRegion command allows one to plot the image of functions whose domain is in $R^2$ and the image is in $R^2$. I tried to use TransformedRegion with a function of $R^3$ into $R^3$ but it did not work and there is no TransformedRegion3D command.
reg = DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]

f[x_, y_, z_] := {y*z, x*z, x*y}


Question: Is there some way to plot the image of f in the code above in Mathematica?

What would this look like? Perhaps plot a cloud of random points in a cube and displace them using the function.

But:  mr = MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,      1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0.5, 0.5, 1.5}, {1.5, 0,      0}, {1.5, 1, 0}, {1, -0.5, 0}},    Hexahedron[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]] and \[ScriptCapitalR] =   TransformedRegion[mr,    ShearingTransform[30 Degree, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}]]

treg = TransformedRegion[reg, f] and Region[treg] works as well but on the cloud. It seems to go to hang up on v12.2.0.

TheTransformedRegion command also works in 3D. In your case
reg = ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];
treg = TransformedRegion[reg, 
Function[p, {p[[2]]*p[[3]], p[[1]]*p[[3]],p[[1]]*p[[2]]}]];
Region[treg]



Thanks! There is a missing [ in the code in the answer: p[1]] should be p[[1]]. I tried to edit it but it would not allow for corrections less than 6 characters...

@SergioParreiras" Thank you. Fixed.


The faster way as in my previous answer.
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/279976/72111
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270002/72111

Clear[reg, f];
reg = DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[{0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 0 <= z <= 1}, {x, y, z}],
    MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01];
f[x_, y_, z_] := {y*z, x*z, x*y};
RegionPlot3D[reg, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> f[x, y, z]], 
 MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 2, ViewPoint -> {-2.4, -1.7, -1.7}]



Yes, this is a faster way. However, RegionMember[treg,{x,y,z}] produces x | y | z) \[Element]    Reals && ((x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0) || (x == 0 && y == 0 &&       z == 1) || (x == 0 && y == 0 && z < 1 && z > 0) || (x <= 1 &&       x >= 0 && y <= 1 && y >= 0 && x y - z == 0 && z >= 0) || (x > 0 &&       y > 0 && x y - z <= 0 && z > 0 && -y + x z <= 0 &&       x - y z >= 0) || (x <= 1 && x > 0 && x - y >= 0 &&       y >= 0 && -y + x z == 0) || (x >= 0 && x - y <= 0 && y <= 1 &&       y > 0 && x - y z == 0)), whereas RegionMember[reg, {x, y, z}] doesn't produces an expression.

(i) RegionConvert[treg, "Parametric"] produces ParametricRegion[{{y z, x z, x y},    0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1}, {x, y, z}]. (ii) Indeed, RegionPlot3D  draws better than Region.

@user64494  RegionPlot3D[treg] does not product the smooth graphics3D since treg is too complex althought it is the parametric form.

Every approach has its advantages and deficiencies.

Visualization of how the transformation take place based on @cvgmt answer.
reg = DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[{0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 0 <= z <= 1}, {x, y, z}],
    MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];
f[x_, y_, z_] := {y*z, x*z, x*y};

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot3D[reg, 
  DisplayFunction -> 
   ReplaceAll[{x_Real, y_Real, 
      z_Real} :> (Transpose[{#[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[1]]}] . {n, 1} &@{{x,
          y, z}, f[x, y, z]})], Boxed -> False, Mesh -> 9], {n, 0, 1}]



Manipulate with much quicker response (not based on @cvgmt answer).
lines = {Table[Line@{{n, 0, 0}, {n, 0, 1}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{0, 0, n}, {1, 0, n}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{n, 0, 0}, {n, 1, 0}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{0, n, 0}, {1, n, 0}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{0, n, 0}, {0, n, 1}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{0, 0, n}, {0, 1, n}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{n, 1, 0}, {n, 1, 1}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{0, 1, n}, {1, 1, n}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{n, 0, 1}, {n, 1, 1}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{0, n, 1}, {1, n, 1}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{1, n, 0}, {1, n, 1}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}], 
     Table[Line@{{1, 0, n}, {1, 1, n}}, {n, 0, 1, 1/10}]} // Flatten //
    DeleteDuplicates;
nlines = lines /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {y z, x z, x y};

(Transpose /@ Transpose[{#[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[1]]}]) . {n, 
     1} & /@ (Transpose[{lines, nlines}] /. Line -> Sequence);
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Line[%]}, Boxed -> False], {n, 0, 1}]



